# How to swap parts of $request in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have a short question.
I have $request

/place/foo/bar/

How swap '/place' at the end of request and redirect client with nginx
to /foo/bar/place

Something like this. But $request contain '/place' and I have endless redirect.

```
location /place {
  return 301 $request/place 
}
```

Comment: nginx is a web server engine, and is very large and contains lots of parts. What is `$request` ? which language(s) are you working in and what interface are you using? More clarity is needed, **please edit your question**.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I try to explain more clarity, edited question

Comment: So is this in the `htaccess` or `httpd.conf` file?

Comment: I think `$request` confuses your question because there is an Nginx variable called `$request` which is not relevant to what you are trying to do. Just to clarify, you have a URL that literally begins with `/place/` and you want that prefix moved to the end of the URL by using a 301 redirection? Something like: `rewrite ^(/place)(/.*)?$ $2$1 permanent;`

Comment: yes, right. I want that prefix moved to the end of the URL by using a 301 redirection